# How to put an if statement inside an input's 'min' attribute

Tags: php, html, if-statement, input, min

I want to make an if condition inside the `min=""` attribute of an input element.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" min="1" max="{{ $product_info[0]->quantity - $sessionQty }}" step="1" value="1" readonly>
```

What I want is to be able to write a condition like:

```
min = "if($product_info[0]->quantity - $sessionQty == 0) {
           echo 0;
       } else {
           echo 1;
       }"
```

When my `$product_info[0]->quantity - $sessionQty` would be equal to zero, the minimum value should be set to 0. when the condition is not zero, the minimum value should be set to 1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming it is php code that you are putting inside min in that case this is the working code as below

`min="<?php echo ($product_info[0]->quantity - $sessionQty) == 0 ? '0' : '1'; ?>"`

if `{{}}` is from some templating framework then it should also work like below

`min="{{ ($product_info[0]->quantity - $sessionQty) == 0 ? '0' : '1' }}"`

Comment: Ok do let me know i have not tested it yet.

Comment: Let me test it as well though.

Comment: can you add the condition to let the min. not to be a negative number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153914/discussion-between-jc-john-and-muasif80).